# Finishing a project: Making it into a .exe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using Visual Studio Code, and have just managed to complete my first two Discord bots in Javascript (thanks, of course, to the wonderful community here that helped me substantially to learn the language!). While the bots may receive new commands in the future, for now, I am willing to state that they are in a 'complete' state.

The one final detail - it's pretty annoying to have to find the folder and run them using node . every time. Is there a way in the current version of VSC to build the code into a .exe file? I have seen tutorials online which show how to do it in an older version using the tools menu, however that menu is not visible in my install of VSC, so it's either old or outdated, or some as-yet-unknown setting is hiding it.

Comment: Node is a JavaScript runtime environment, to work with a JavaScript related library outside the browser, you need node.

Comment: I own a few discord bots, and i can't imagine that building it to a exe is less trouble and time consuming then a git pull origin master && node index.js. There are existing tools that can do it for you tho. If finding the location is your problem, i would make a bash script i could trigger that boots the bot

Comment: ^Well, yeah, converting it to a .exe would be time consuming... except it only has to be done once. The current method has to be done EVERY TIME I go to boot up the bot. I'm looking to cut down on the long-term complexity of just 'turning the bot on'.

Comment: @RobertHalal just create a bash or shell script, paste your command into the file, and double click it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read you are using `NodeJS`, so I would like to introduce you `"Nexe"`. This is a command-line-utility to compile your `NodeJS` Application to use it on the different operating systems.

You can find it here on `Github`:

https://github.com/nexe/nexe

It's super easy to use and deploy.